# Android: Распознавание картинок и текста

Tags: android, java

Есть около 20-40 картинок.

И есть фото: задача найти похожее изображение из тех 20-30 картинок.

Какая библиотека способна на такое?

И ещё: интересует распознавание текста (не больших объёмов - до 5 символов).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала Вам нужно определиться с критерием схожести. Если для Вас этот критерий к примеру "коты или собаки изображены на изображениях", то это задача далеко не тривиальная.

Если же критерием схожести является то, что изображения почти идентичные (например две фотографии на фоне Кремля, только на одном глаза закрыты), тогда это проще. Картинки уменьшаются в много раз, так что бы их размер стал порядка 20 на 20 пикселей (размер подбирается под задачу). Перед этим их можно перевести в оттенки серого.

Теперь, когда все изображения одного размера, их легко сравнить попиксельно. Если перед этим перевели изображения в оттенки серого, то ещё легче, потому что для каждого пикселя будет диапазон 0-255. и разница в пару единиц может считаться одним цветом. После этого выбираете те изображения, для которых совпадений больше. Скорее всего это и будут одинаковые изображения.

> > И ещё: интересует распознавание текста (не больших объёмов - до 5 символов).

капчи распознаем?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам посоветовал посмотреть в сторону [OpenCV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV).